# Sikuli produces unreliable/random results

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

In the application I am automating, I have two buttons: Login, and Sign Up.

They both have different icons. Sometimes (and by that I really do mean completely at random with no behavior pattern) my script to click the login button will click the sign up button. This is even more confusing because the sign up button does not exist in my image repository.

I am clicking on it like so:

```
try {
        s.click("/imagerepo/config/loginbutton.png");
    } catch (FindFailed e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sometimes it will  click the login button. Sometimes not.

I am really confused as to what is going on here. Are there any methods to configure how exact the image has to be for Sikuli to find it? How do I improve the reliability of my scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, when Sikuli behavior is unclear, you have to debug your script and understand what is really happening compared to what you thing is happening. In some cases, you similarity coefficient is too low and other pattern can be picked instead the one you wanted. Try to follow the below steps to debug your Sikuli script.

1. Use `highlight()` method

   So before your click, try to do something like this:

   `s.find("/imagerepo/config/loginbutton.png").highlight(1); //1 sec highlight duration`

   This will display a rectangular red frame around the located element on the screen.
2. When using `highlight()`, have a look at the console. It should print out the Match object details. It will look something like this:

   `[log] highlight M[12,9 38x38]@S(0)[0,0 1280x1024] S:1.00 Center:31,28 for 1.0 seconds`

   Pay attention to the `S` parameter which is `1.00` in this case. That's your similarity coefficient. Generally, values above 0.95 means that there is a 95% match between your pattern and some element on the screen. If this value is low though, you can expect some weird behavior that could lead to matching incorrect elements. You can find some more information about Match object [here](http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/understanding-sikuli-match-object.html).